# Read Domino console output programmatically

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have an agent (actually a 'runjava task', but that does not really matter), it runs on server and gather some stats from Domino:

For example the code issue a command like below:

```
String console = session.sendConsoleCommand("", "!sh server");
```

that returns output into 'console' variable and I get needed data from it.

While other commands like:

```
String console2 = session.sendConsoleCommand("", "!tell runjava show tasks");
String console3 = session.sendConsoleCommand("", "!trace server1");
```

Return:

> Command has been executed on remote server. Use 'Live' console option, in future, to view response from server.

I tried another approach and output result into file using code (no success)

```
String console2 = session.sendConsoleCommand("", "!tell runjava show tasks >file1.txt");
String console3 = session.sendConsoleCommand("", "!trace server1 >file2.txt");
```

and also via program documents like below (no success)

[image]

but that gives me same result:

> Command has been executed on remote server. Use 'Live' console option, in future, to view response from server.

Is there a way to get output from Domino console somehow? (as you can see I'm fine to output results into file and read it later on with agent)

Any ideas are welcome :-)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What if you access ªData\IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT\ and read the current file console.log?

Comment: It seems it does not log all commands, for example it logs [trace server1] while another command like [repair list missing] is not logged for some reason. So it's not very reliable solution (though I have to go that direction as far as I see).
Thanks for reply!